# Recursively define a variable in Stata with conditions

Tags: stata, recurrence

I want to generate a variable recursively with certain conditions. Let's call the variable **x**. **x** is generated differently under different conditions.

1. **x_t=L1.x_t^a + b/2** if **L1.x_t^a+b<c** and **L1.x_t > d**
2. **x_t=1+0.5x_t^a**     if **L1.x_t^a+b>c** and **L1.x_t > d**
3. **x_t=L1.x_t^a** if **L1.x_t < d**

I know how to implement this in R but not sure how I go about doing this in Stata. I have tried the following 2 pieces of code but none worked.

---

```
gen x = 1
forvalues i = 2/_N {
    scalar temp = x[`i'-1]^a + b
    replace x = x[`i'-1]^a + b/2 if temp < c & x[`i'-1] > d
    replace x = 1 + x[`i']/2 if temp > c & x[`i'-1] > d
    replace x = x[`i'-1]^a if x[`i'-1] < d
}
```

---

```
gen x = 1
gen temp = L.x^a + b
replace x = L.x^a + b/2 if L.x > d & _n > 1 & temp < c
replace x = 1 + L.x^a/2 if temp > c & _n > 1 & L.x > d
replace x = L.x^a if L.x < d & _n > 1
```

The first piece of code gives an error `invalid syntax`. The second piece of code didn't deliver what I thought it would. I know where the problem lies, that is `temp` should be replaced after every call of `x`, but I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bizarre-looking set of conditions!

There are several details that stop all your code examples being reproducible by anyone else.

1. Anyone else needs to `set` the number of observations.
2. You need to explain `a b c d` as entities in Stata. Are they variables, constants held as variables, or constants held as scalars?
3. For a lag operator `L.` to work, you need to `tsset` or `xtset` the dataset first, implying at least one other variable that indicates time or sequence, but this is not explained.

A specific problem with the first block of code is that `forvalues` won't evaluate `_N` for you. You need to go

```
forval i = 2/`=_N'
```

A general problem with that block of code is that you probably want each `replace` statement to be

```
... in `i'
```

"didn't deliver what I thought it would" is not a problem I can address. Without a worked example showing what the calculations should produce and what they do, I am clueless.

Comment: Ah yes I did skip a bit in the explanation for the first 3 points. The problem I was referring to is that since `temp` is generated before the variable `x`, the condition with respect to `temp` is only true for `x` available before `temp` was calculated which is `x[1]=1`, thereby invalidates all the conditions thereafter (or rather they are not calculated). I managed to make it work by rerunning the piece of code using the `forval` loop for every observation.

Comment: Good that you solved your problem: I don't understand the comment, however, and the thread is unlikely to be useful to anyone else as  neither your precise problem nor your  precise solution is at all clear.  I recommend deleting the thread unless you can improve the question and provide your own answer.